# How do I remove 'Print' from the context menu with ShellMenuView?

Tags: context-menu

[This ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/855946) avouches that 'print' ought appear:

> [image]

but why doesn't it for me? Please see below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you figured this out by now, but for future right-click-print-haters: you need to uncheck "Options -> Hide Standard Menu Items" which is checked by default.

The Windows default "Print" that appears below "Open" for many file types, and results in thousands of pages of paper being wasted daily, will then appear in the list. Type `CTRL+Q` to show the "Quick Filter" control, filter on "print", and then you can disable it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the registry with [`reg delete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-delete) command in Command Prompt. Let `.txt` file as an example.

- Get the file extension association: `assoc .txt`
- Delete the registry as administrator: `reg delete HKCR\txtfile\shell\print /F`
- Sometimes there is also another registry: `reg delete HKCR\txtfile\shell\printto /F`

Backup the registry if needed. The deleted registry can be easily imported from .reg file. The command can also be used in a `for` loop for multiple file associations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking in the wrong place, at the wrong entries.

The screenshot in the answer you linked dates from some time ago and probably from
another version of Windows.

The `Print` entries can be found under other names, such as `&Print` and
`3D Print` (the new nifty print option in Windows 10).

Here are some examples from my computer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. +1. I hope others, like me. to upvote your answer that helps as much as that which I accepted. I accepted another answer not by reason of any difference in helpfulness, but because SE allows only one acceptance that I have bestowed to those with less reputation.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + F to find entries. Type "print". Press enter. I see that Print's actually "&Print" on the list. Note: "&" here means hotkey (underlined letter), so &Print becomes **P**rint in the context menu and Pre&view becomes Pre**v**iew.

Alphabetic sorting puts things beginning with "&" at the top, together with the other &'s (&Edit, etc.) That's why you didn't find it between pre**v**iew and re**p**air. It's between **&P**lay and **&R**egister instead, a lot higher up on the list. Here is a ShellMenuView picture:
[image: ShellMenuView]

Addendum: When modifying your shell via registry, sometimes changes are only applied on the next login. So log out and back in (or reboot your whole machine, whichever is more convenient for you) and check again. It might have worked!

Advanced: Hate logging out? Me too! Open Task manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) and terminate explorer.exe (Windows Explorer) and then launch it again via: File → Run new task. It will reload your shell — with the new registry changes applied — without logging you out or closing your running applications.

(Edit: Rewrote my whole answer, misunderstood question.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you do not need 3-rd party SW just to edit the context menu. You can simply run a `*.reg` to get rid of that option. I specifically made my own and [I am quite pleased with the result](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/WindowsBatches/blob/master/RegistryMods/Remove%20Print%20on%20Context%20Menu.reg). In a standard windows installation the location `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\textfile\shell` for example contains the commands that are ran by the context menu selection in CMD under the hood. It has varieties of options like `open`, `print` and so on. The print command specifically in this case will run: `"%ProgramFiles%\Windows NT\Accessories\WORDPAD.EXE" /p "%1"` which passes the first argument being the `right-clicked` file name with a `print` option to wordpad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Done. With an example.